# How can i make a ListViewBuilder to have a dynamic height according to the number of items that it build?

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll, rendering, singlechildscrollview

I'm having quite lot of problems to render the items of a **ListViewBuilder** with a **dynamic height**, meaning that the height will change accordingly to the number of items that i want to render. Moreover, the listview is **NeverScrollable** since i wrapped it with a **SingleChildScrollView** to scroll the listView together with other widgets as a unique widget. Finally, the **shrinkWrap** is set to True for the listViewBuilder.
The **problem** is that if i fix the height of the TabBarView, which contains the ListViewBuilder, to a value which is bigger than the all items summed up height, then i will be left with white space! On the other hand, if the height is smaller, then some items aren't rendered!!! Do you have any solutions for this? Thanks!

Below the code:

1. This the **HomePage**: i have a Column with a Container for the search bar and a **FoodPageView()** (this last one is expanded) as children:

```
  const HomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: 1,
        selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            label: 'Cart',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Me',
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20,
                left: 10,
                right: 10,
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.blue[100],
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            width: 0,
                            style: BorderStyle.none,
                          ),
                        ),
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 20,
                        ),
                        hintText: "Search store",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 10,
                    ),
                    height: Dimensions.height50,
                    width: Dimensions.width50,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      color: Colors.amberAccent,
                    ),
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.search_outlined,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: Dimensions.height20,
            ),
            const Expanded(child: FoodPageView()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

2. The **FoodPageView()** implementation: it contains a Column with children a **PageViewBuilder**, a **DotsIndicator** and finally a custom **NavigationBarTab()**

```
  const FoodPageView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FoodPageView> createState() => _FoodPageViewState();
}

class _FoodPageViewState extends State<FoodPageView> {
  final PageController _pageController = PageController(
    viewportFraction: 0.85,
  );
  double _currPageValue = 0.0;
  final double _scaleFactor = 0.8;
  final int _height = 300;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _currPageValue = _pageController.page!;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: Dimensions.height290,
            child: BlocBuilder<ProductsBloc, ProductsState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                final List<Product> productsPromos = state.products
                    .where((product) => product.hasPromo == true)
                    .toList();

                return PageView.builder(
                  controller: _pageController,
                  physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: productsPromos.length,
                  itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                    Matrix4 matrix = Matrix4.identity();
                    if (index == _currPageValue.floor()) {
                      final double currScale =
                          1 - (_currPageValue - index) * (1 - _scaleFactor);
                      final double currTrans = _height * (1 - currScale) / 2;
                      matrix = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1)
                        ..setTranslationRaw(0, currTrans, 0);
                    } else if (index == _currPageValue.floor() + 1) {
                      final double currScale = _scaleFactor +
                          (_currPageValue - index + 1) * (1 - _scaleFactor);
                      final double currTrans = _height * (1 - currScale) / 2;
                      matrix = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1)
                        ..setTranslationRaw(0, currTrans, 0);
                    } else if (index == _currPageValue.floor() - 1) {
                      final double currScale =
                          1 - (_currPageValue - index) * (1 - _scaleFactor);
                      final double currTrans = _height * (1 - currScale) / 2;
                      matrix = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1)
                        ..setTranslationRaw(0, currTrans, 0);
                    } else {
                      const double currScale = 0.8;
                      final double currTrans = _height * (1 - _scaleFactor) / 2;
                      matrix = Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1, currScale, 1)
                        ..setTranslationRaw(0, currTrans, 0);
                    }

                    return Transform(
                      transform: matrix,
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: Dimensions.height200,
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              right: 10,
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                image: AssetImage(productsPromos[index].image),
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            child: Container(
                              height: Dimensions.height100,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 30,
                                right: 30,
                                bottom: 15,
                              ),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                boxShadow: const [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    blurRadius: 5,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 5),
                                  ),
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    blurRadius: 0,
                                    offset: Offset(-5, 0),
                                  ),
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    blurRadius: 0,
                                    offset: Offset(5, 0),
                                  ),
                                ],
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                              child: Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 10,
                                  top: 10,
                                  bottom: 10,
                                ),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            productsPromos[index].name,
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 20,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                          const Text(
                                            'Offer',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 15,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          const SizedBox(height: 5),
                                          Text(
                                            '${productsPromos[index].promo!.percentagePromo}% Off',
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 17,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ]),
                                    const Icon(
                                      Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_outlined,
                                      size: 40,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          BlocBuilder<ProductsBloc, ProductsState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              final List<Product> productsPromos = state.products
                  .where((product) => product.hasPromo == true)
                  .toList();
              return DotsIndicator(
                dotsCount: productsPromos.length,
                position: _currPageValue,
                decorator: DotsDecorator(
                  activeSize: Size(Dimensions.width20, Dimensions.height10),
                  activeShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                      5,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height5),
          const NavigationBarTab(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

3. The **NavigationBarTab()** page below: it is a Column with a **Tab Item Menu** followed by the corresponding **tabView page**. Each tabView page is a ListViewBuilder **FoodListView()**

```
  const NavigationBarTab({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NavigationBarTab> createState() => _NavigationBarTabState();
}

class _NavigationBarTabState extends State<NavigationBarTab>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TabController tabController = TabController(
      length: 4,
      vsync: this,
    );
    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 30,
          child: TabBar(
            isScrollable: false,
            controller: tabController,
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
            tabs: const [
              Tab(
                text: 'Pizza',
              ),
              Tab(
                text: 'Specials',
              ),
              Tab(
                text: 'Desserts',
              ),
              Tab(
                text: 'Drinks',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 700,
          child: TabBarView(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            controller: tabController,
            children: const [
              Expanded(child: FoodListView()),
              Expanded(child: FoodListView()),
              Expanded(child: FoodListView()),
              Expanded(child: FoodListView()),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

4. Finally the **FoodListView()** page: a ListViewBuilder with NeverScrollable physics and shrinkWrap to true.

```
class FoodListView extends StatefulWidget {
  const FoodListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FoodListView> createState() => _FoodListViewState();
}

class _FoodListViewState extends State<FoodListView> {
  final PageController _pageController = PageController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ProductsBloc, ProductsState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        final List<Product> products = state.products
            .where(
              (element) => element.hasPromo == false,
            )
            .toList();

        return ListView.builder(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: products.length,
          itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
            return FoodCard(
              index: index,
              products: products,
            );
          }),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

5. The **FoodCard()** is a Container with fixed height.

```
  final int index;
  final List<Product> products;
  const FoodCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.index,
    required this.products,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FoodCard> createState() => _FoodCardState();
}

class _FoodCardState extends State<FoodCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ProductsBloc, ProductsState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Container(
          height: 125,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 5,
            right: 5,
            top: 5,
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 5,
                  left: 5,
                  bottom: 5,
                ),
                height: Dimensions.height120,
                width: Dimensions.width120,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: AssetImage(
                      widget.products[widget.index].image,
                    ),
                  ),
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 5,
                  ),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 5,
                    bottom: 5,
                    right: 5,
                  ),
                  height: Dimensions.height120,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            widget.products[widget.index].name,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: Dimensions.height10,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Stack(children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: Dimensions.height150,
                                width: Dimensions.width210,
                                child: Text(
                                  widget.products[widget.index].description,
                                  maxLines: 4,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ]),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: Dimensions.height5,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '\$ ${widget.products[widget.index].price}',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: Dimensions.height30,
                        width: Dimensions.width30,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.amber,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.shopping_cart,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What if you leave out the height?

Comment: @Ivo it gives me an exception "Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height."

Answer (score 0):

When you try two use `Expanded` widget indirectly inside `column` or `row` widget, you you should wrap the parent with `Expanded` too, so remove the `SizedBox` and do this:

```
Expanded(
  child: TabBarView(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            controller: tabController,
            children: const [
              FoodListView(),
              FoodListView(),
              FoodListView(),
              FoodListView(),
            ],
          ),
),
```

Comment: i get another exception: The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Comment: @Andi I updated my answer again, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can either move the whole widget inside a expanded. Which is considered the most used way of doing it. Like this ->

```
Expanded(
   child: TabBarView(
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: _yourController,
        children: const [
          FoodListView(),
          FoodListView(),
          FoodListView(),
          FoodListView(),
        ],
      ),
   ),
```

**For this you'll have to remove the ScrollView you're using.**
Or In your wayyy, What you can try doing is, Enabling
-> "shrinkWrap: true,"
inside your ListView.Builder(). And in both ways, you should be able to get rid of the fixed height you're providing now.

Comment: the first option gives me "RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded." It seems that i need to give him the height. The shrinkWrap is already set to true.

Comment: Extremely sorry, I forgot to mention this, But in the first scenerio you should remove the SignleChildScrollView that you're using rn. Im updating my answer.

Comment: Ok, but if i remove the SingleChildScroll then just the listviewbuilder will be scrollable, whereas i want all the widget to be scrollable.

Comment: Aaaah I see, What you're looking for is Sliver widgets. But you can achieve it this way, but that will be supper like a sneaky way to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replacing the **TabBarView** with a **IndexedStack** widget. It Works pretty good!!
Here's the code of the indexedStack:

````
IndexedStack(
          index: _selectedIndex,
          children: [
            Visibility(
              visible: _selectedIndex == 0,
              maintainState: true,
              child: const FoodListView(
                category: "Pizza",
              ),
            ),
            Visibility(
              visible: _selectedIndex == 1,
              maintainState: true,
              child: const FoodListView(
                category: "Specialities",
              ),
            ),
            Visibility(
              visible: _selectedIndex == 2,
              maintainState: true,
              child: const FoodListView(
                category: "Desserts",
              ),
            ),
            Visibility(
              visible: _selectedIndex == 3,
              maintainState: true,
              child: const Text("index 3"),
            ),
          ],
        )```
````